# how can i make this .bat file is the previous line does not work

Tags: batch-file

net use w: https://xxxxx.xxxxxx.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /user:johnny ********

net use j: \HPSTORAGE\Users\johnny /user:johnny ********

net use s: \HPSTORAGE\Storage /user:johnny ********

net use v: \HPSTORAGE\Videos /user:johnny ********

copy c:\users\johnny\downloads j:\johnny\downloads

del /q c:\users\johnny\downloads\

thats my .bat file that i am using and it works great.. I would like to make it stop the rest of the .bat file from running if the line, **net use j: \HPSTORAGE\Users\johnny /user:johnny **********  fails to work. i am have tried everything i know and looked every place i know to look.  thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  %ERRORLEVEL% as shown in the following article:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/132733/gc/DOS-batch-file-error-handling

Answer (score 2):

The suggestions of using errorlevel and goto all work, but the solution can be even simpler

```
net use j: \HPSTORAGE\Users\johnny /user:johnny ** || exit /b
```

The command after || is only executed if the prior command failed.

Comment: Use this to fail silently or with %ERRORLEVEL% to use some form of logging or cleanup.

Answer (score -2):

i do not think this is possible with .bat file scripting, i think you should resort to another programming language to solve this.

Comment: Are you implying that branching is impossible in batch files? Because that's completely incorrect.

Comment: You generally need to use goto's

Comment: There are `IF` statements... Gotos are not a requirement. But certainly they are an acceptable solution.

Comment: Cody Gray did i say it was impossible?